# Codeigniter website with out database generating database error on live server

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, connection-string

I have developed a website with out any database using codeigniter, this site is working fine on local host but when I uploaded this site to live server this is showing the database error. 
link to website is :
http://flojoco.com/dev/sabor-latino/
I have left the values for database.php empty as follows:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

I dont know how to solve this problem now. 
Any help much appreciated in advance.

Comment: what do you have in your config/autoload.php? is the DB being initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto **config/autoload.php** and check this array:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('libary1','libaray2','database'); // example
```

You are loading **database** library in autoload file, so please remove the database library.

Comment: yes, I was loading "database" library. THanks for resolving the issu @devpro

Comment: @shahid-rafiq Mubarak ho bhai.. Glad to help u